# OpenGL program using version 1.1, gpu supports OpenGL 4.0

Tags: c#, opengl, driver

I'm on my laptop with the Intel HD 4000 GPU. I updated my GPU drivers. The OpenGL Extensions Viewer says that my OpenGL version is 4.0. But when I check which version of OpenGL I am using in my program using glGetString, it says that I use version 1.1! How do I force my program to use OpenGL version 4.0?

Comment: Microsoft Windows, right? Do the other strings such as `GL_RENDERER` and `GL_VENDOR` report something along the lines of "GDI" and "Microsoft"? If so, you are getting a software pixel format. This usually happens because you request something really unusual like a 64-bit accumulation buffer and a 16-bit color buffer, bitplane shifts, etc. If the hardware does not support the pixel format you request, but the GDI implementation does, Microsoft will give you a software format. Please update your question to include the code you are using to request your pixel format / render context properties.

Comment: If you create an OpenGL Context specifying the needed context version as being 1.1, then `glGetString(GL_VERSION);` will return 1.1, and not 4.0, as `glGetString(GL_VERSION);` returns the version of your current context.

Comment: Yes! GL_RENDERER says GDI Generic! What was causing the problem, is that I was requesting a 32-bit per pixel depth buffer. Now I turned it down to 24-bit per pixel, and it works well. Really great help, thank you!